# "Мэр Краснодара" или "Мэр г.Краснодара"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Как в соответствии с правилами русского языка необходимо писать вот это:
- вариант 1: мэр Краснодара;
- вариант 2: мэр г.Краснодара

Answer (score 1):

Правила допускают оба варианта. Только после точки нужно ставить пробел.

Примеры из Национального корпуса русского языка:

> Причиной разногласий стало письмо за подписью **мэра Саратова** Юрия Аксененко. [Александр Крутов. «Радиоприборный завод»: от «красного директора» к внешнему управлению (2003) // «Богатей» (Саратов), 2003.04.24]
>
> **Мэр г. Саратова** Юрий Аксёненко получил новое высокое назначение. [Маргарита Спиричева. Льстивый черный пиар (2003) // «Богатей» (Саратов), 2003.10.16]